# How do I run a spring boot executable jar in a Production environment?

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot's preferred deployment method is via a executable jar file which contains tomcat inside.

It is started with a simple `java -jar myapp.jar`.

Now, I want to deploy that jar to my linux server on EC2, am I missing something or do I really need to create a init script to properly start the application as a daemon?

If I simply call `java -jar` the application dies when I log out.

I could start it in screen or nohup but that is not very elegant and a restart in my server would force me to log in and start the process manually.

So, is there something already for the task in spring boot?

Comment: nohup/screen (dirty method), init/systemd/upstart (proper method)

Comment: @RC Yep, that much I know, like I mentioned, /sbin/init with a custom script in /etc/init.d, would do the job, but is it really the idea that everyone should build his own script to manage the daemon (start, stop, restart, status)? Feels like something is missing on that solution.

Comment: I you feel that something is missing in spring-boot (it's a really "fresh" project btw) just contact the team in charge and make an evolution proposal.

Comment: Well, if you generate a war archive you can use your distribution's version on Tomcat which will have a init script ready to use. On the other hand, if you use the executable jar approach, you have to come up with your own custom init script. Not sure if that is on boot's realm, but it is clearly missing, which is kind of weird, hence me asking in case I overlooked something. Will ping them.

Comment: See [here for existing discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/519) and ideas.

Comment: I use nohup for testing purposes.

Comment: Is deploying it as a jar recommended for a production environment, or is it better to create a war and deploy on a regular Tomcat container?

Comment: Just start a service as it was noted in other question.

[Java As a service Linux][1] or the java wrapper [Java Service Wrapper]:[2]

[2]:http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/launch-nix.html
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux

Comment: See also [Spring Boot application as a Service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23537896)

Answer (score 106):

Please note that since Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1, you are able to build fully executable jars using Maven and Gradle.

For Maven, just include the following in your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For Gradle add the following snippet to your `build.gradle`:

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

The fully executable jar contains an extra script at the front of the file, which allows you to just symlink your Spring Boot jar to `init.d` or use a `systemd` script.

`init.d` example:

```
$ln -s /var/yourapp/yourapp.jar /etc/init.d/yourapp
```

This allows you to start, stop and restart your application like:

```
$/etc/init.d/yourapp start|stop|restart
```

Or use a `systemd` script:

```
[Unit]
Description=yourapp
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/yourapp/yourapp.jar
User=yourapp
WorkingDirectory=/var/yourapp
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

More information at the following links:

- [Installation as an `init.d` service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing.init-d)
- [Installation as a `systemd` service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing.system-d)

Comment: You might also need to do `$ chmod +x /etc/init.d/yourapp` to be able to start/stop/restart

Comment: You always have to give your service user permissions to read and execute the jar file. You also have to configure the default Java for the server and Java environment variables to make things work.

Comment: This doesn't work! I have tried it and I get the following error:Failed to start MyApp.service: Unit MyApp.service not found

Comment: what is the kotlin syntax for springBoot { executable = true } ?

Comment: @nayandhabarde My Kotlin based gradle config has tasks.withType<BootJar> { launchScript() } and I execute ./gradlew bootJar

Answer (score 13):

By far the most easiest and reliable way to run Spring Boot applications in production is with Docker. Use Docker Compose, Docker Swarm or Kubernetes if you need to use multiple connected services.

Here's a simple `Dockerfile` from the official [Spring Boot Docker guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) to get you started:

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

An even better approach for building Docker images is to use [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib), an open-source Java tool maintained by Google for building Docker images of Java applications. Jib does not need a `Dockerfile`, you just invoke it with Maven (official quickstart [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#quickstart)) or Gradle (official quickstart [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#quickstart)).

Here's a sample command line to run the container as a daemon:

```
docker run \
  -d --restart=always \
  -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod" \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  prefix/imagename
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows OS without Service.

**start.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
call run.bat start
```

**stop.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
call run.bat stop
```

**run.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="start" (
    ECHO start myapp
    start "myapp" java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=staging myapp.jar
) ELSE IF "%1"=="stop" (
    ECHO stop myapp
    TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq myapp"
) ELSE (
    ECHO please, use "run.bat start" or "run.bat stop"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

My Spring boot application has two initializers. One for development and another for production. For development, I use the main method like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppInitializer .class, args);
    }

}
```

My Initializer for production environment extends the **SpringBootServletInitializer** and looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppInitializerServlet extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(SpringBootServletInitializer.class);
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        log.trace("Initializing the application");
        return builder.sources(MyAppInitializerServlet .class);
    }

}
```

I use gradle and my build.gradle file applies '**WAR**' plugin. When I run it in the development environment, I use **bootrun** task. Where as when I want to deploy it to production, I use **assemble** task to generate the WAR and deploy.

I can run like a normal spring application in production without discounting the advantages provided by the inbuilt tomcat while developing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In a production environment you want your app to be started again on a machine restart etc, creating a /etc/init.d/ script and linking to the appropriate runlevel to start and stop it is the correct approach. Spring Boot will not extend to covering this as it is a operating system specific setup and the are tonnes of other options, do you want it running in a chroot jail, does it need to stop / start before some other software etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the application called [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).
In supervisor config you can define multiple services and ways to execute the same.

For Java and Spring boot applications the command would be 
`java -jar springbootapp.jar`.

Options can be provided to keep the application running always.So if the EC2 restart then Supervisor will restart you application

I found Supervisor easy to use compared to putting startup scripts in /etc/init.d/.The startup scripts would hang or go into waiting state in case of errors .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gradle you can just add this to your build.gradle

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

You can then run your application by typing ./your-app.jar

Also, you can find a complete guide here to set up your app as a service

**56.1.1 Installation as an init.d service (System V)**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

cheers

Comment: Actually that turns out it should be
`bootRepackage { executable = true }`
See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

I start applications that I want to run persistently or at least semi-permanently via screen -dmS NAME /path/to/script. As far as I am informed this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple, you can use spring boot maven plugin to finish your code deploy.

the plugin config like:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debug.port}
                    </jvmArguments>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>test</profile>
                    </profiles>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And, the `jvmArtuments` is add for you jvm. `profiles` will choose a profile to start your app. `executable` can make your app driectly run.

and if you add `mvnw` to your project, or you have a maven enveriment. You can just call`./mvnw spring-boot:run` for mvnw or `mvn spring-boot:run` for maven.