# How IDEA compile and run maven based application?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

my problem is following:
I have project based on maven. This project has two modules `A` and `B`. `A` used `B`.  `A` is spring-boot project.
I have also third `pom.xml` - it is only root for these two projects. When I import project in IDEA (I point as `pom.xml` root project) it correctly imports it. Moreover, when I click 'play' it correctly compiles and runs application.

I can't do it without IDEA.  Can you help me ? How to do it with only console ?

Comment: cd to the directory containing the third pom.xml, and type in `mvn`.

Comment: may be you are looking for this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31654838/7212399

Comment: I would like to see what commands IDEA sends to maven. I am convinced that it doesn't call `spring-boot:run` during clicking play

Comment: When you click "play" you can tell what configuration is begin run. It's name is right next to the play button. Click the drop down, click Edit Configurations and and find the one by the name displayed in the drop down.