# How to create Environment variable (space) in AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I have used Elastic BeanStalk to host our web application. In web application, I have used the environment variable assigned with some location to push the files into that.

I have set the VENDOR_HOME as,

```
       D:\Applications\spring-boot\Resume_folder
```

and accessing through java using  System.getenv in as

```
       String path = System.getenv("VENDOR_HOME");
```

It is working fine in the local tomcat server, I want the same functionality should achieve in AWS too? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your BeanStalk application, go to the `Configuration` page. Locate `Software Configuration`. Click on edit. You have the option to add `Environment Properties` at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helps. I got the option to add the Environment variable. one small clarity, can I access that variable using System.getenv("VENDOR_HOME"); ?

Comment: and where can I create the folder like /Applications/spring-boot/Resume_folder

Comment: Such files and folders are usually created in `src/main/resources` folder of your Java project.

Comment: ofcourse, we can do that, but my requirement is to place the files in the AWS space. same like our local folder.

Comment: Then you can place those files in S3 and use its path in your application.

Comment: yes, I have created a folder in S3. what is the path here? where can I get the path? is this URL or something else? please clarify me.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat typically has a setenv.sh file where admins can set environment variables.  In the setenv.sh file you can put a line for your VENDOR_HOME variable as such:

```
export VENDOR_HOME=/Applications/spring-boot/Resume_folder
```

For AWS BeanStalk specifically you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17878600/1490322) for details on how to set the env variables.

In general you can set Linux environmental variables using the export command from within the script you are using to execute your application.  The final answer will depend on how you are executing your application.

I typically use [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654838/1490322) that creates executable JAR files.  The executable JAR file allows for a config file with the same name as the JAR file (.config instead of .jar) where admins can export environmental variables from.

Comment: Hi jsoe, Thank you for your answer. I have created a folder in S3. how can I get the path to use in an environment properties?