# Deploy a JAR file to a VPS server (Ubuntu Server 16.04)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, ubuntu, vps

I need to deploy my spring boot rest api to my VPS server, to do so I installed JAVA and MAVEN. I ran it using `sudo java -jar myfile.jar` it is working but the problem is that after sometimes it stops and my webservice send me `error 503`.

I would like to know how to deploy it and run without it stopping.

PS : There is no page ".html" to be accessed that's the reason I want to deploy as JAR

Comment: The run it in a correct way. I think, it's important to understand why it's stopping, it might be failing with an error.

Comment: Look at the way how run your SpringBoot application as a service. It's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654838/731938