# Is there a way to run spring boot without ./mvnw install? e.g java Main.java

Tags: java

My goal is to create a Docker image. However, the `./mvnw install` takes way too long time.

What I've did:

1. I tried to run `java com.personal.bebankaccount.BeBankaccountApplication.java`. It throws:

   ```
   Error: Could not find or load main class 
   com.personal.bebankaccount.BeBankaccountApplication.java
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
   com.personal.bebankaccount.BeBankaccountApplication.java
   ```

I use IntelliJ IDEA and pressing `CTRL+R` will run the application. However, the problem is I am want to run this application on a Docker image.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886083/how-do-i-run-a-spring-boot-executable-jar-in-a-production-environment By the way, the `java` command takes a class name, not a source file name.

Comment: How did you run it, using this command -  ./mvnw spring-boot:run ?

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov I run it with either of these, `CTRL+R` while inside IntelliJ IDEA or create docker image. The docker image take way too long time on step `./mvnw install`.

Comment: @kidfrom this command runs the application as a Stand alone project. If you need to run it in a docker file, you should build the app and make a docker file using an already created the jar. Let me know if you need more details on that

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov I did build the app. However, my Mac Mini M1 are having issue to create the `.jar`. So,I handle everything inside `Dockerfile`. I uploaded the [Dockerfile file](https://github.com/kidfrom/be-bankaccount/blob/master/Dockerfile) for reference.