# Add additional parameters to Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, maven, service, spring-boot, init.d

I am wondering if it's possible to add spring's additional parameters such as `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` to spring boot app in case of running it as a [service](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-service).

I checked the script that was generated automatically by `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

`command="$javaexe -jar -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $jarfile $@"`

so maybe it can be done via maven plugin's options, but couldn't find any except of JVM arguments which is not so useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution including the one I described in question - it seems that plugin's additional params also don't work.

At the end I solved it by using [systemd service approach](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-systemd-service).

Looks like that and works perfectly:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some app
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar /home/apps/monitoring-app-1.0.0.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working? Failing big time for me.

Comment: Something like "invalid syntax". Sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Yes I could not start the service

Comment: It should say java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar /home/apps/monitoring-app-1.0.0.jar (note monitoring-app-1.0.0.jar follows the -jar parameter) I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use external configuration file for example.

Based on the documentation if you provide an `application.properties` file in the `./config` directory next to the executed jar you can set up the active profile through that properties file.

Just use `spring.profiles.active=myprofile` in `./config/application.properties`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: It seems that does not even overwrite the default application.properties inside the jar file, which is great.

Answer (score 4):

Create a .conf file in the same directory with the same name as your executable jar e.g.

```
server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.conf

JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx500m \
-Dspring.profiles.active=myprofile"
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file