# Spring Boot app fails to start up using SSH

Tags: java, spring, bash, ssh, deployment

I have a spring app that is happily running on a staging and a prod server. It's time to automate deployments.

I have a `restart.sh` script on my staging server. if I `ssh` into the server and run it as a user everything works as expected.

command to run: `nohup ./restart.sh`

```sh
# restart.sh
kill  $(ps -aux | grep plenti-app | grep java | awk '{print $2}')
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=staging plenti-app
```

However, when I attempt to run the command *through* ssh, it fails saying that password authentication for my database fails.

`ssh user@$STAGING_IP "./restart.sh"`

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "gszbybjk"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:520) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
```

I first suspected that this might have to do with environment variables since that's how I'm storing the database credentials, but ssh calls to `ssh user@ip echo $DB_PASSWORD` result in the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was going about this the wrong way. There's a whole subsystem dedicated to launching service applications called `systemd`

Here are several links to help any future travelers get started

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-systemd-service
- [Add additional parameters to Spring Boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242291/add-additional-parameters-to-spring-boot-app)
- [Spring Boot application as a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/spring-boot-application-as-a-service)