# Is it possible to set spring.datasource.driver-class-name via environment variables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As described in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), configuration can be passed via environment variables. However there are some configuration properties like `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` which contain hyphens. When setting this in bash you will get an error:

```
$ export SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
bash: export: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver': not a valid identifier
```

This is because variables in bash must not contain hyphens. So is it even possible to set Spring configuration properties which contain hyphens via environment variables?

Comment: Check if this helps http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-include-character or you can consider passing them as java system properties instead i.e., `-Dspring.datasource.driver-class-name=....`

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu that would certainly do the trick, thank you! But I want to pass the configuration as environment variable, so it doesn't really help in my case ;-)

Comment: Try replacing the hyphens with underscores. The relaxed binding should do the work

Comment: What version are you using? Try `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`

Comment: @joshiste that did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll it works. However it is a bit confusing. When setting `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME` only `spring.datasource.driver.class.name` is set while `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` will be null. All of the docs just talk about the latter, that's why I was going with the hyphens.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Does my solution work? (it should). Feel free to open an issue/PR with more details please.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll yes it does work. Thank you!

Comment: @joshiste do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring Boot provides a [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding). For this reason the environment variable `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME` can be used to set the driver class name.

Comment: `DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`? The table in the link you provided suggests it is `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVERCLASSNAME` (`.`→`_`, but `-` in name are just dropped, not also converted to `_`s).

Comment: @JanHudec I found this link that may answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612891/4230091