# Properties with underscores in docker-compose.yml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, docker, docker-compose

I have webbapp based on Spring. To configure it I use .yml files. 
To convert environmental variable from spring/backend .yml format to docker-compose.yml environment section I have to change indents into underscores. Example:

application.yml

```
spring:
  mail:
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    environment:
      SPRING_MAIL_PROPERTIES.MAIL.SMTP_AUTH: true
```

But some property names contain underscores itself. Like this:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

How should I translate such properties (with underscores in names) to the environment section in docker-compose.yml?

**This question is not a duplicate**. Mentioned similar question does not answer my question. Question [How to set a Spring Boot property with an underscore in its name via Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178556/how-to-set-a-spring-boot-property-with-an-underscore-in-its-name-via-environment) is about how to represent properties with underscores in Spring Boot and accepted answer shows how property file entry is interpreted by Spring. There is a link to `SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java` class which is responsible for translation and interpretation of properties in Spring. My question asks about .yml file interpretation in **Docker-Compose**. So I need basically similar answer to the accepted one in the mentioned thread but about how **Docker-Compose** interprets .yml properties to environment variables.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for that issue? I have the same scenario with spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=BIND that I want to inject via ENV settings. The underscores in the ENV settings become dots and the config is not picked up

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't.

Comment: @luke You can pass it as JSON with the environment variable `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config