# Spring weird behavior for overriding variables in application.properties with environment variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am using Spring Boot 2 and by reading the doc about externalilzing properties  [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), I expect that I can override the value of a variable in application.properties by declaring an os environment variable of the same name.

So I tried as follows.

First, declare following 2 variables in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
my.prop = hello   
myProp = hello
```

Next, create `src/main/java/me/Main.java` with following content.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    @Value("${my.prop}")
    String myDotProp;

    @Value("${myProp}")
    String myProp;

    @Value("${my.env.prop}")
    String envDotProp;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        logger.debug("my.prop : " + myDotProp);
        logger.debug("myProp : " + myProp);
        logger.debug("my.env.prop : " + envDotProp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, using Windows Environment variables panel to declare 3 variables as in the picture below.

[image]

Finally, run `mvn spring-boot:run`, and this is the result

```
2018-04-21 14:41:28.677 DEBUG 22520 --- [main] me.Main : my.prop : hello
2018-04-21 14:41:28.677 DEBUG 22520 --- [main] me.Main : myProp : world
2018-04-21 14:41:28.677 DEBUG 22520 --- [main] me.Main : my.env.prop : world
```

Please notice that

1. Spring can see the environment variables regardless of whether the have dot (.) in the variable name or not, as shown in `myProp` and `my.env.prop`
2. Spring can override the value of a variable in `application.properties` using the value of the os environment variable of the same name **only if the name does not contain dot (.)** as shown in `myProp` and `my.prop`: the value of `myProp` has been successfully override to `world` but the value of `my.prop` stays `hello` even I have os env variable `my.prop` declared.

**Is there a reason for this behavior and is there a way to configure Spring so that I can use dot in my properties variables as well as overriding them using os env variables?**

Comment: When using system environment variables, it's recommended to use uppercase symbols though, so you should set `MY_ENV_PROP`, `MY_PROP` and `MYPROP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.` in your environment variables by `_`.
For example if in Spring Boot the property is named `my.env.prop` in order to override it use an environment variable named `my_env_prop` and Spring does the conversion automatically.

The reason for the issue with `.` is that some operating systems do not support `.` in environment variables names.

Similar issue discussed here: [How to set a Spring Boot property with an underscore in its name via Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178556/how-to-set-a-spring-boot-property-with-an-underscore-in-its-name-via-environment)