# Spring Boot Application Properties Variable Conversion/Matching when retrieved from ENV variable?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-properties

In my application.yaml properties file I have a variable defined as below -

```
service-account:
#   secret:  //commented in the yaml file, to indicate that it's used in app but read from ENV variable.
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178556/how-to-set-a-spring-boot-property-with-an-underscore-in-its-name-via-environment) SOF post, I understand how . (dots) and - (dashes) are converted.
Now in the ENV variables file - I don't have anything like -

`service-account.secret` or `service-account_secret` or `service_account_secret` etc

instead what i have in the env (file) is - `SERVICEACCOUNT_SECRET=xyz`

Does spring boot match variable `service-account.secret` in props file with `SERVICEACCOUNT_SECRET` env variable.

Can someone confirm.

Comment: No, there wont be automatic matching. You will need to assign the ENV var to your property by using the syntax `secret: ${MY_ENV_VAR}` in your yaml

Comment: @Tobi - i have tested it and you also should try. Automatic Matching is done.

Comment: Can you provide me any reference in the spring boot docs? I could not find any

Comment: @Tobi - i tested it through code.. i am not aware of a reference that i can share. I would suggest that you too test it and share your findings here so it helps others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does spring boot match variable `service-account.secret` in props file with `SERVICEACCOUNT_SECRET` env variable.

Yes. The canonical form of a property is all lower-case with `-` and `.` separators. `service-account.secret` is in the canonical form. To convert from the canonical form to an environment variable, Spring Boot [does the following](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables):

- Replaces dots (.) with underscores (_)
- Removes any dashes (-)
- Converts to uppercase

Following these steps, `service-account.secret` becomes `SERVICEACCOUNT_SECRET` so you can use the `SERVICEACCOUNT_SECRET` environment variable to set the `service-account.secret` property.

Comment: gr8.. that helps +1.  A related Q - does ENV values take precedence over inline value in yaml.

Comment: Yes they do. See [this section of the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).