# How to run spring-boot as a service in linux

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring-boot application as a service in linux box so that I can start and stop it as a jenkins job.

As per the suggestions in for this question [Spring Boot application as a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/spring-boot-application-as-a-service) I created the soft link

```
$sudo link -s /opt/jenkins/workspace/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
```

Now when I am trying to run it from the jenkins command prompt I get command not found

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/myapp start
sudo: /etc/init.d/myapp: command not found
```

I am using spring boot 1.3 and java8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the executable flag (chmod +x myapp.jar)?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that! :-) but I am not able to stop it, the command `$ sudo /etc/init.d/myapp stop` doesn't seem to understand the stop param

Comment: Did you follow the complete guide at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-service?

Comment: You can build maven rpm package on Linux and install through YUM.