# Spring boot application as Service - Running in foreground instead of daemon

Tags: linux, spring-boot, startup, init.d

I followed  the standard tutorials out there in Spring website and couple of private articles.

1. create a symbolic link of the jar to /etc/init.d/
2. service myapp start

The service starts but it starts just like a normal app in foreground. Just like I ran

java -jar myapp.jar on the terminal

How do I make it run in the background just like mainstream linux services

This is my script

```
sudo chmod 500 myapp.jar
sudo /path/to/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
```

And I run the service as

```
sudo service myapp start
```

This is now running the app in foreground holds up the console , instead of  running as service

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/spring-boot-application-as-a-service

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the answer is, you must set embeddedLaunchScriptProperties > mode to "service" in spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin! This way your application will run as a service.

Answer (score -1):

Just add an `&` at the end of the `java -jar yourApp.jar` in your service script, this forks a process instead of using the process that calls the `start`.

```
java -jar yourApp.jar &
```

Comment: is it a clean solution. Coz.. even the official document does not say anything like this!

Comment: It's a clean solution for running a process in the background, regardless of where it's used (init.d or elsewhere in your terminal/bash). If you want more advanced checks like preventing double starts, you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux, as @Avinash pointed out...

Comment: OK..But why has not these been mentioned in the doc. So is it expected for spring boot to run as foreground?