# How to Extern log4j.properties file with Spring Boot Microservice and Run It As a Linux Service?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, log4j

Have a Spring Boot (1.5.4.RELEASE) based microservice which I deploy a jar to an AWS EC Instance (Linux environment). Now, I am also deploying an external log4j.properties file so I have to start the microservice like this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar -Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j.properties
```

How can I configure this Spring Boot Microservice as a Linux service where I can start and stop it using these flags:

```
sudo service myapp start | stop | status | restart
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to write a java service wrapper. this example could be useful. http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example

Comment: This is all pretty well explained in the official documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service

Comment: I hope the answer you will get here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/spring-boot-application-as-a-service

Comment: Is your question about stopping and starting it on Linux, externalising the properties, or both ?

Answer (score 5):

Using a symbolic link to your springboot app you can make it controllable as service...

```
sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
```

Placing an `application.properties` into your myapp folder you can override the one bundled inside your app. This way you don't need to use command line switches. Simply specify the path to your log configuration as value to property key `logging.config` inside of it.

NOTE, though, that this solution is not really best practice. Once you're running a whole bunch of services in production, you probably rather want to go for something along the lines of [spring cloud config](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) for externalizing configuration and you probably also want your logs aggregated at a centralized service that allows for an overview of all your services' logs in one place.

Comment: Please write some explanation.

Comment: @Jörg, But how do I write this part (when issuing the symoblic link):             
 -Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j.properties

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover thanks for patiently asking once more - see my update

Answer (score 1):

As per [spring-boot deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html),

> A fully executable jar can be executed like any other executable binary or it can be registered with `init.d` or `systemd`

Make sure you build your app using the plug-in below (gradle version in shared link):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and as shown by Jörg, create a symbolic link inside init.d:

```
sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
```

That is the simplified version :)

More to your question, you need to customize the init and this can be done by a `conf` file - all specified in the documentation.

> With the exception of `JARFILE` and `APP_NAME`, the settings can be
>   configured using a .conf file. The file is expected next to the jar
>   file and have the same name but suffixed with .conf rather than .jar.
>   For example, a jar named /var/myapp/myapp.jar will use the
>   configuration file named /var/myapp/myapp.conf.

such as:
**myapp.conf**

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024M
LOG_FOLDER=/custom/log/folder
```