# Create Windows Service from Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, windows-services

I'm trying to start Spring Cloud Dataflow as Windows service. To do this I downloaded `winsw` from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSW/) (version `2.1.2`). My config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <id>my-id</id>
    <name>my-name</name>

    <executable>java</executable>
    <startargument>-cp</startargument>
    <startargument>spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar;cp/*</startargument>
    <startargument>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</startargument>
    <startargument>--spring.profiles.active=productin</startargument>
</configuration>
```

After running this commands:

```
myApp.exe install (it's renamed winsw.exe)
myApp.exe start
```

I find this in log file:

```
2017-12-05 09:48:54,459 INFO  - Starting ServiceWrapper in the service mode
2017-12-05 09:48:54,485 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
2017-12-05 09:48:54,500 INFO  - Starting java  -cp spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar;cp/* org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --spring.profiles.active=production 
2017-12-05 09:48:54,500 INFO  - Starting java  -cp spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar;cp/* org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --spring.profiles.active=production 
2017-12-05 09:48:54,515 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
```

and nothing happens... Server is not running, there is no more logs. If I try to run it from Control Panel > Services, I'm getting info that service has started but then stopped.

How can I properly run Spring Boot app as Windows Service?

Comment: HI please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/spring-boot-application-as-a-service/49150048#49150048 . Its clearly mentioned for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Maybe try to compile all arguments in `<arguments></arguments>`