# GUI javafx app not opening via service in linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, raspberry-pi, debian

I have created a GUI Javafx app and exported it to a jar file. The GUI app is working fine. After creating this app i have moved it to linux system and it is working fine here. Now i want to run this GUI app in linux using services so that i can make this service run at start of linux system.

For that I have created a pointless.sh file which on run runs the jar file. It is working perfectly the code for this pointless.sh file are

```
java -jar GUI1.jar
```

on Runinng this script i.e. "./pointless" the GUI is shown on the screen. 
[image]

Problem starts when i try to make a service for it.

I made a service for it in /etc/systemd/system pointless.service

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/mandeep/Documents/pointless.sh
```

on running sudo systemctl start pointless.service nothing happens and the status shows following errors.

```
● pointless.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pointless.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-07-06 13:44:00 EDT; 25min ago
  Process: 1449 ExecStart=/home/mandeep/Documents/pointless.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1449 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 06 13:44:00 debian systemd[1]: Started pointless.service.
Jul 06 13:44:00 debian systemd[1449]: pointless.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/mandeep/Documents/pointless.sh: Exec format error
Jul 06 13:44:00 debian systemd[1]: pointless.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 06 13:44:00 debian systemd[1]: pointless.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 06 13:44:00 debian systemd[1]: pointless.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Update !!!**

**Step 1**
As expected I created a simple Java app helloworld and exported it to jar file. I ran this file as java -jar helloworld and It worked.

**Step 2**
I created a simple service for it and service also worked as expected.
the service codes are

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/mandeep/Documents/helloworld.jar
```

**Output**

```
Jul 07 17:08:13 debian systemd[1]: Started pointless.service.
Jul 07 17:08:13 debian java[2765]: Hello World!
```

**Step 3**
I Updated service back to GUI1.jar to check original problem posted.
code

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/mandeep/Documents/GUI1.jar
```

and again it shows the error

Output

```
● pointless.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pointless.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-07-07 17:14:37 EDT; 4s ago
  Process: 2816 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/mandeep/Documents/GUI1.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2816 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian java[2816]:         ... 5 more
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian systemd[1]: pointless.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian systemd[1]: pointless.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 07 17:14:37 debian systemd[1]: pointless.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: In your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916159), your screenshot *CUT OFF THE SINGLE MOST IMPORTANT PIECE OF INFORMATiON*.  The error message: `Exec format error`.  This is a systemd error.  Look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303022/systemd-exec-format-error and here: https://superuser.com/questions/944244/running-a-java-process-from-systemd

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank YOu for the information. Yes I know this is a systemd error. But how to resolve it is the problem. The posts you mentioned are informative but does not solve the problem for me yet.

Comment: @paulsm4 any suggestion would be appreciated if you need the jar file i ll post it to you.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need the .jar file.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Please read this additional link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503883/, 2) modify your script to start with `#!/bin/bash`, include the fully qualified path to Java, and echo $PATH, $JAVA_HOME and $CLASSPATH.  Copy/paste the output into your original post. 3) If you still can't figure it out, then write a JavaFX [MCVE] that reproduces the problem and copy/paste it into your original post.

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried running a simple java jar and its working as expected and when i go back to same GUI1.jar it produces error. This time error may look different because i am not running script i am running jar file directly from service. This may help to understand issue. Please see the update. Thank You!!!

Comment: OK: that's useful information.  So the problem is *NOT* with the script, and the problem is *NOT* with the difference between running your script from command line vs. from systemd environments.  Q: So what exactly is the difference between the .jar that "works", and the one that doesn't?  Q: You aren't trying to run GUI code as a service, are you?  If so: Q1: Why?  Q2: How do you expect that to work?  SUGGESTION: I still recommend an [mcve].

Comment: @paulsm4 i figured the problem was with graphics and user level. Somehow the terminal should know to use graphic etc and ther terminal should have right user for calling it. I have added solution below and it works as expetced. But dont know the real reason i.e. working of these codes so if you know please post it. Thank You !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer

Made following changes under [Service] in pointless.service

a) use "`Environment=DISPLAY:=0`"

b) declare "`User=<user>`"

and under [Install] optional

c) declare "`WantedBy=<user>@.service`"